# What is the difference between an accelerated LAN port and a regular non-accelerated port?

Tags: router, port, switch, local-area-network

Can someone explain the difference for me?

Wondering more about the difference for the end user, but a technical description would also be helpful.

Comment: This sounds like vendor specific terminology. What product are you talking about?

Comment: That may be the case which would explain why I can't find any information on them online. It's on a kit that, while it has a very specific use, is essentially an expensive portable router. No idea who makes it but it's probably General Dynamics or Raytheon or some such company. All I know is that the official recommendation is to put user devices like laptops on the accelerated ports, and printers or VTC kits on the non-accelerated one. Just trying to figure out what the actual difference is.

Comment: Without knowing the context, any answer is pure speculation.

Comment: It's not a standard term, so you'll need to read the vendor documentation. (I don't even know what you mean by VTC.) If you had access to the command line or GUI on the router, it could be that the ports have different line speeds.

Comment: VTC=video teleconference. My initial assumption was that the non-accelerated have limited throughput so that more important devices have enough bandwidth when all the ports are in use.

Comment: That's a terrible assumption, to be honest, since you don't know the priority algorithm in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, an "accelerated port" is typically a port on a piece of hardware that is accelerated for a specific use via vendor-specific methods.  For example, Citrix's Branch Repeater "accelerated ports" to which WAN acceleration is applied.  If you have a VTC switch the accelerated ports may have algorithms applied to their traffic (via software or via ASICs)  designed to increase throughput when used with VTC protocols or data, perhaps through QoS or compression, or perhaps the opposite if the ports have acceleration that might interfere with the normal operation of VTC.